# Can a ClickOnce deployed application push an update to specific users?

Tags: clickonce, auto-update, uat

I'm assessing various ways of deploying a C# desktop application and I'm wondering how developers do UAT when working with a ClickOnce application.

We maintain a list of users who have agreed to participate in our UAT program for our application and I'd like to specify that these users get the update first before I approve the change and push it to the rest of our users.

Therefore, if I wanted to deploy the program as a ClickOnce application is there a way for me to tell ClickOnce which users I want to push the next update to and then after passing UAT, let ClickOnce push the update to all users currently using our tool?

I can see a workaround where I deploy a second ClickOnce application called "Tool_Name_Beta", but I was hoping not to have to manage two separate ClickOnce deployments.